# How can I handle click event on a node in dracula graph library?

Tags: jquery, graph, graphdracula

Given a simple node, I'd like to handle click event on a node.

For example when you click on "cherry" on the page http://www.graphdracula.net/, an alert should popup.

ps: need new tag "dracula" but I don't have enough reputation to create it...

Comment: Hi my friend, I'd like to know how did you assign id for each node in "render" function? thanks.

Comment: See my last comment below the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cant you simply do

```
$("#cherryID").live('click',function(){

//code here
});
```

Comment: Well, yes. The problem seems to be elsewhere, the node's id will be the node's label, if you specify that.

Comment: can you show a litte bit of your markup, you can use `#` for id selector

Comment: the line `g.addNode("cherry_id", {  label: "cherry"})` will result in an svg element with an incorrect id `cherry`. However a custom render function solved the problem.

Comment: I can't see any ID in any of the node. Can you tell me how to handle this?

Comment: Have you added the node like the example I've written right above your question?